# Access an element in List 2D in Python

Tags: python, list, 2d

I have a list 2D

```
a = {}
a[0,0] = 1
a[0,1] = 2
a[1,0] = 3
a[1,1] = 4
a[1,2] = 5
...
a[1,n] = 6
```

Now, I want to access the element a[1,x] (x = is 0 to n) 
How can I do?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064277/2d-array-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a nested loop if I understand what your asking for.

```
somearray = [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]]
for row in range(len(somearray)):
    for col in range(len(somearray[row])):
        print(somearray[row][col], end =" ")
```

will output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```